# Node is not being inserted after random number of times, Binary Search Tree (C++)

Tags: insert, binary-search-tree

As you will see in the below output, nodes with values 10 and 15 are not being added.
The whole code is below
..............
.............
...............
..............
.............

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SPACE 10

class TreeNode{
public:
    int value;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode(){
        value = 0;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }

    TreeNode(int v){
        value = v;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
 };

 class BST{
 public:
    TreeNode *root;

    BST(){
        root = NULL;
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        if(root == NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    void insertNode(TreeNode *new_node){
        if(root == NULL){
            root = new_node;
            cout<<"Node entered at root"<<endl;
        }
        else{
        TreeNode *temp = root;

        while(temp!=NULL){
            
            if(new_node->value == temp->value){
                cout<<"Node already exist"<<endl;
                break;
            }

            else if((new_node->value < temp->value) && (temp ->left == NULL)){
                temp->left = new_node;
                cout<<"Inserted at right"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (new_node->value < temp->value){
                temp = temp->left;
                break;
            }
            else if((new_node->value > temp->value) && (temp ->right == NULL)){
                temp->right = new_node;
                 cout<<"Inserted at left"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (new_node->value > temp->value){
                temp = temp->right;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }

    
    void print2D(TreeNode * r, int space) {
        if (r == NULL) // Base case  1
            return;
        space += SPACE; // Increase distance between levels   2
        print2D(r -> right, space); // Process right child first 3 
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = SPACE; i < space; i++) // 5 
            cout << " "; // 5.1  
        cout << r -> value << "\n"; // 6
        print2D(r -> left, space); // Process left child  7
  }




 };

int main(){
     BST obj;
     int option, val;
     do {
     cout << "What operation do you want to perform? " <<
  " Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit." << endl;
cout << "1. Insert Node" << endl;
//cout << "2. Search Node" << endl;
//cout << "3. Delete Node" << endl;
cout << "2. Print/Traversal BST values" << endl;
//cout << "5. Height of Tree" << endl;
//cout << "6. Clear Screen" << endl;
cout << "0. Exit Program" << endl;

cin >> option;
//Node n1;
TreeNode *newNode = new TreeNode();

switch (option){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        cout<<"Insert Node"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter the value of the node"<<endl;
        cin>>val;
        newNode->value = val;
        obj.insertNode(newNode);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"Print value"<<endl;
        obj.print2D(obj.root, 5);
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Enter appropriate option"<<endl;
} //switch
}while(option!=0);
}



OUTPUT:
What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program

1
Insert Node
Enter the value of the node 
30
Node entered at root

What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program 
1
Insert Node
Enter the value of the node
18
Inserted at right

What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program
1    
Insert Node
Enter the value of the node
45
Inserted at left

What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program
1
Insert Node
Enter the value of the node
10

What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program
1
Insert Node
Enter the value of the node
15

What operation do you want to perform?  Select Option number. Enter 0 to exit.
1. Insert Node
2. Print/Traversal BST values
0. Exit Program
2
Print value

               45

     30
               18
```

As you see the node 10 and 15 is not being added to the tree. I've tried every single way.
Plz if anyone has solution do provide it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make temp=temp->left in first else if block and remove second else if block and do same for 3rd and 4 th else if block

Comment: Yes, I'll try this one. Thank you very much but I got the error fixed. I just had to remove the "break;" statement from the 2nd and 4th else if block.